# How did the warrior lodges help to spread the Heresy?

Tags: warhammer-40k, horus-heresy

There are several mentions of the warrior lodges in the *Horus Heresy* books. According to the books, this helped Lorgar to spread the heresy. From [Lexicanums Warrior Lodge Article](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Warrior_Lodge):

> The Warrior Lodges were a group of secret fraternities formed by members of the Space Marine Legions during the Great Crusade. They eventually led to the division of the Legions into factions that facilitated their fall to Chaos and the start of the Horus Heresy. Warrior Lodges were covertly spread by the Word Bearers, who had secretly fallen to Chaos, as a means to subvert the loyalties of each Astartes Legion.

This is an abstract from *The First Heretic*. I couldn't find the passage yet but will add it when found. I just can't really understand how these lodges helped Lorgar to spread his heresy. Was it simply to undermine the hierarchy or has there been more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### You could say anything during a Warrior Lodge meeting, regardless of rank.

Rank didn't exist during meetings, all Brothers were treated as equals so any Marine was free to express his opinion about the Legion or Imperium at large, without fear of reprisal or punishment. Marines from other Legions could speak at Lodge meetings also, an excellent vehicle for the traitors message.

Knowing this, traitor Marines used Lodge meetings to spread their philosophy that the Emporer had abandoned them and returned to Terra to be worshiped as a god, while they were dying for the Imperium.

---

I'm having trouble remembering the passage, but the best examples of the Lodges being subverted in this way were likely during the events [Horus Rising](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Horus_Rising_(Novel)).

Comment: Initially the meetings where never as overt as that, the actual spreading of the new philoposhy was not begun until after the fall of Horus, the lodges where largely used initially to determine who would be open to doing things differently, who was willing to use the lodges for personal gain. marines complained about the remembrances and attention was taken to see how other reacted. Some marines where taken into the confidence of Erebus or other word bearers but these where very few and far between at the start.

Comment: Once the heresy began proper then the activities in the lodges was used to identify who should be brought into the inner circle, but, at this point it was still down to the Primarchs to decide. Later the Lodges where then used to help maintain control, marines used them to usurp power and control, or to keep others down.